# SQL Query: Reference Another Table data for two variables in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I'm trying to run a MYSQL query where I need the same 'piece' of information from the source table twice in the destination...
Let me explain:

2 Tables: "**Events**" and "**Archived Events**".
The "Archived Events" is a 'link' - bridging current open events to past (closed) events.
This table only contains id's to the Event_ID in the Events table.

What I want to do is get the Event Title for each combination in the archive table.

EG:

```
   -----------------------------------
   |       ARCHIVE TABLE             |
   |PK|ClosedEventID |CurrentEventID |
   |1 |      5       |       3       |
   |2 |      2       |       3       |
   -----------------------------------

   -----------------------------------------
   |      EVENTS TABLE                     |
   |Event_ID | Event_Title | ............. |
   |    1    | Party 1     | ............. |
   |    2    | Party 2     | ............. |
   |    3    | Wedding 1   | ............. |
   |    4    | Funeral 1   | ............. |
   |    5    | Pancake     | ............. |
   ----------------------------------------
```

I'm guessing it's going to be a join or a union or something; my SQL is fair, but my head is spinning trying to work this out.

So what I would like done is that for each 'pair' in the archive events table would look like this once the query was run (so that I can deal with it in PHP...):

```
   -----------------------------------
   |       ARCHIVE TABLE             |
   |PK|ClosedEventID |CurrentEventID |
   |1 | Pancake      |   Wedding 1   |
   |2 | Party 2      |   Wedding 1   |
   -----------------------------------
```

Thank you for your help in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly simple:

```
SELECT
    a.pk as "pk",
    e1.event_title as "closed_event",
    e2.event_title as "current_event"
FROM
    events as e1
    JOIN archive as a on e1.event_id = a.closed_event_id
    JOIN events as e2 on a.current_event_id = e2.event_id
```

Comment: "Fairly Simple"; In hindsight, yes - but I'm the type to overcomplicate :P

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT PK, e1.Event_Title AS ClosedEventID, e2.Event_Title AS CurrentEventID
FROM   ARCHIVE
  JOIN EVENTS AS e1 ON e1.Event_ID = ARCHIVE.ClosedEventID
  JOIN EVENTS AS e2 ON e2.Event_ID = ARCHIVE.CurrentEventID
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6aa4a/2).

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: I understand the theory of joins, it's just been a long time since I used them - and my sql text book was no help.
Never knew about sqlfiddle - quite handy, thanks :)